# In Objective-C, should a wrapper property be set to weak?

Tags: objective-c, properties

In Objective-C, should a wrapper property be set to weak? By wrapper property I mean that the property is a wrapper of another property.

e.g.

```
- (Prop *)prop {
  return self.obj.prop;  //wrapper method for another property
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) Prop *prop; // weak or strong?
```

Comment: Given that you're not synthesizing `prop`, you should probably just offer a `prop` method in the header.

Comment: It's nicer to declare it as property because it is a property, readonly in this case.

Comment: A property is a description of an instance variable and accessor methods. What you have is just a method. You can use a property for that but it isn't 'correct' to do so.

Comment: @Wain What's a readonly property then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"correct" in this case is a matter of convention and preference as Objective-C properties do support this pattern. Accessing a property does call a method which is either generated, synthesized or manually coded.

I'll stay out of whether it's "correct" or not.

Since your property only returns the value of a different property, then you don't need to specify strong or weak as they are meaningless.

In the public header:

```
# myclass.h

@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, readonly) OtherClass *someProperty;
@end
```

In the implementation:

```
# myclass.m

@implementation MyClass

- (OtherClass *)someProperty
{
    return self.someObject.otherProperty;
}
```

Comment: If you are don't specify, it's strong by default, correct?

Comment: for a readwrite property backed by an iVar, yes, the default is `strong`. Strong/weak don't apply to readonly properties.

Answer (score 0):

Using a property is not necessarily the best way to go. It shouldn't really be weak or strong as it will never be set. You are never going to create a readwrite counterpart and generate an instance variable / accessor methods.

So, it's better to represent this as a simple method in the header file. It's more accurate as a description of the interface offered.

Comment: I made it readonly because it's never set.  Are you saying readonly property should not be declared as such?

Comment: I would use a readonly property only if that was the public interface and privately I was going to redeclare as readwrite (because then the strong / weak actually means something)

Comment: I disagree but it is purely a matter of style and taste